# Can a photon turn a proton into a neutron?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, standard-model

My guess it's yes, if the photon has enough energy to make up for the mass difference.
I imagine the following:

1. the photon turns into an electron+positron pair
2. the electron hits the proton and forms a neutron (and some neutrino?)

At the same time I remember reading that gamma rays cannot activate materials, i.e. they are unable to alter nuclei, so that suggests it shouldn't be possible.

Comment: You might not need a photon; β+ emission works fine in, e.g., $^{23}_{12} Mg \to ^{23}_{11}Na + e^+ + \nu_e$...

Comment: ENDF has no cross section data for gamma reactions with a proton.

Comment: You do need the photon for an *isolated* proton. An isolated neutron can break down to a proton and an electron with an antineutrino and energy left over.

Answer (score 24):

For photons with $E_\gamma > 151\,\textrm{MeV}$, photoproduction of positive pions will turn protons into a neutrons, i.e. $\gamma p \rightarrow n \pi^+ $.  This has been observed in [many experiments](https://www.hepdata.net/search/?q=gamma+p+--%3E+n+pi).

For photons with $E_\gamma > 2\,\textrm{MeV}$, the process you propose ($\gamma p \rightarrow n e^+ \nu_e$) is possible in principle, but it requires producing a virtual W boson and the chance of it happening will be very tiny, presumably less than the probability a neutrino with a comparable energy interacting with a proton.

By the way, any particle (including photons) can activate materials if they have enough energy to break up nuclei. For example,  blasting aluminum nuclei with electrons at [SLAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLAC_National_Accelerator_Laboratory) produced lots of short-live isotopes [such as Na-22 and Na-24](https://www.slac.stanford.edu/pubs/slacpubs/1250/slac-pub-1406.pdf).

Comment: "can activate materials"; I saw the starburst from when a lambda particle got captured like a neutron into a nucleus and then decayed.

Comment: I wouldn't call $^{22}\mathrm{Na}$ short-lived, it has a 2.6 year half life and is somewhat commonly used as a positron source (but maybe I just have a different definition of short-lived)

Comment: @Ilama You are certainly correct that Na-22 would not be considered "short-lived" in other contexts.  I guess since activation was mentioned, I was immediately thinking ["radioactive waste management"](https://www.radioactivity.eu.com/site/pages/Shorl_Lived_Fission_Products.htm), where "short-lived" is anything less than 5 years or so.